# How to send in URL parameters into Socket Connection

Tags: c#, sockets

I am currently working on a project that required To use TCP or Socket connection. Because I was give a URL to let me connect to it , and the server will push data to me.

The given URL is http://member.sugacane.com/userInfo?userid=2&token=SomeToken

I go through MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7.aspx) and grab some sample code to work on it.

```
public static void StartClient(string Host, string token, int userID, int port)
        {
            Host = "member.sugacane.com";
            string Datamsg = "userid=2&token=SomeToken";
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];


            try
            {

                //  uses port 80.
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostEntry(Host).HostName); 
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port); 

                // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
                Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
                try
                {
                    sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                    Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                        sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                    string isConnect = "Socket connected to {0}" +sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

                    // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Datamsg);

                    // Send the data through the socket.
                    int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                    // Receive the response from the remote device.
                    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    string res = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                    // Release the socket.
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();

                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I am able to connect to the server with this code , but I could not get any response , The byte always 0 , it should return some XML data. I am wondering is that I sending in wrong `Datamsg`

Comment: Check update to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You should use http protocol. Check sample session from wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol. Sending only url is not enough for the server to come up with response.

It looks like this:

REQUEST:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Etag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 131
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

You may use telnet to check if the messages you try to send are correct. Another option is to paste your link in browser and check what is sent to the server using Fiddler or Wireshark.

**UPDATE**

For example if you change first lines of your code like this you should get response from wikipedia:

```
Host = "en.wikipedia.org";
string Datamsg = @"GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1
Host: en.wikipedia.org

";
```

So your code should look like (I'm leaving the part where you should place valid token, etc.):

```
Host = "member.sugacane.com";
string Datamsg = @"GET /userInfo?userid=2&token=SomeToken HTTP/1.1
Host: member.sugacane.com

";
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering is that I sending in wrong Datamsg

If the server you're connecting to is an HTTP server then yes, you are sending an incorrect request. Use libraries like [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) or [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for this.

Comment: That is the URL , i must use socket connection to connect , Do you know how to send in parameter or message for socket connection ?

Comment: @abccba _"i must use socket connection to connect"_ - who told yo so? Use an HTTP client library if you want to perform an HTTP request. Don't do sockets.